# How to solve Kotlin File Error in Newer Version of Android Studio: HedgeHog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I updated my Android Studio to the latest update HedgeHog. Whenever I run Kotlin File, I get this error : Operation is not supported for read-only collection.

I updated Kotlin Version too...

My Kotlin Version: 231-1.9.10-release-459-AS9392.1.2311.11076708 (The updated one)
Kotlin Compiler Version: 1.9.21
Language Version: Latest Stable (1.9)
API Version: Latest Stable (1.9)

I was expecting a proper run of the Kotlin File but there are no resources available online to get reference from for this issue.

This is the code for which I was working:

```
fun main() {
var computerChoice = ""
var playerChoice: String

println("Rock, Paper or Scissors? Enter your Choice: ")
playerChoice = readLine() ?: ""

val randomNumber = (1..3).random()

if (randomNumber == 1) {
    computerChoice = "Rock"
} else if (randomNumber == 2) {
    computerChoice = "Paper"
} else {
    computerChoice = "Scissors"
}

println(computerChoice)
```

}

Comment: It would be helpful to show the code that gives this error. Also this seems like an error that should also have happened before any update of Android Studio

Comment: Sure, I have added the code. Kindly guide. It will be a great help from your side...

Comment: To me nothing in that code seems to be able to throw that error. I think it's actually trying to run some other code. Maybe show us the full stack trace

Comment: Thankyou so much Sir for the quick replies. When I updated to the newer version, this issue came. 

This issue got solved now when restored the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I restored to defaults.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Restored what to what defaults ?

Comment: Hi,
I did it this way: 
Start your Android Studio, at the top menu bar, then select “File” > “Manage IDE Settings” > “Restore Default Settings”